# gzip decoding error when using Python requests but not curl

Tags: python, python-requests

I'm making a POST request of some JSON to an endpoint (Vertex AI Endpoint) and the request works when I make it via curl:

```bash
curl \
-X POST \
-H "Authorization: Bearer $TOKEN" \
-H "Content-Type: application/json" \
$API_URL \
-d "@input.json"
```

but if I try the same in Python:

```py
with open("input.json") as f:
    input_dict = json.load(f)

response = requests.post(
    url,
    json=input_dict,
    headers={
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
        "Authorization": f"Bearer {token}"
    }
)
```

I get the following exception:

```py
requests.exceptions.ContentDecodingError: ('Received response with content-encoding: gzip, but failed to decode it.', error('Error -3 while decompressing data: incorrect header check'))
```

I inspected the headers to see the difference between the curl request and the python one and I see in Python, the header `Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate` is added to the request. Is this causing a problem and if so, is there a way I can modify it?

Also, if I modify the request to decode the raw response, I can use it correctly:

```py
response = requests.post(
    url,
    json=input_dict,
    headers={
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
        "Authorization": f"Bearer {token}"
    },
    stream=True
)
    
parsed_response = json.loads(response.raw.read().decode('utf-8'))
```

but I'm still trying to understand why the first option doesn't work and where the issues lies.

Comment: That _almost_ implies that the server is claiming to send back compressed data when the result is actually uncompressed; if it were really compressed, your `parsed_response` when referring to the raw content would be binary data, vs the expected JSON... though it's possible there's still decoding done by requests except when `stream=True`; I'd need to dig into the details to have enough certainty to write a proper answer.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Yeah my understanding is that requests is adding a header that curl doesn't (accept-encoding: gzip) and the server is complying by sending back a gzipped response but not actually encoding it. I'm not sure how to get requests to not include auto include that header since that seems to be throwing it off and I'm not sure I can fix the server-side issue myself